# Immutable class accessors in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I am trying to implement objects similar to `CNContact` and `CNMutableContact` such that I can retrieve my immutable objects from a custom store and make editions only to mutable copies of the objects.

To tackle this I have taken a look at the `CNContact` source available through Xcode to find this:

```
open class CNContact : NSObject, NSCopying, NSMutableCopying, NSSecureCoding {


  /*! The identifier is unique among contacts on the device. It can be saved and used for fetching contacts next application launch. */
  open var identifier: String { get }


  open var contactType: CNContactType { get }

  ...

}
```

However when I try something similar I get an error:

```
class MyModel: NSObject, NSCoding, NSSecureCoding {

  // MARK: - Properties

  var name: String { get }

  ...
}
```

The error being `Expected '{' to start a getter definition`. What am I doing wrong here?

The next step then would be to have a mutable subclass, very similar to `CNMutableContact` which would looks like this:

```
class MutableMyModel: MyModel {

  // MARK: - Properties

  var name: String

  ...
}
```

If my approach to this problem is sensible then why am I seeing this syntax error, and why is it valid within the Apple written code but not my own?

Finally am I going to hit any issues within my subclass where I am essentially redefining the name property?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Is it just about the syntax error trying to declare your `name` property? If so, please focus your question on that specific issue. Most of the info in your question has nothing to do with that problem.

Comment: The syntax `var name: String { get }` is valid only in a protocol definition. In Swift an immutable accessor is just `let`. There are fundamental differences in ObjC and Swift semantics. Never try to translate literally.

Comment: @vadian Interesting. If this is the case, how was it possible for the Apple written code to do this within a class?

Comment: @tomasbasham You can't see Apple's code. You are looking at a translation of an Objective-C _header_ file.

Comment: @matt Ah I see. That makes a lot of sense. So I assume from this that the particular framework I'm looking at is still written in Obj-C and as you say I'm just looking at a translated interface?

Comment: All of Cocoa is "still written in Obj-C" And you do not have to "assume" anything. You are looking at the "generated interface". That means it is translated from Objective-C to Swift mechanically for you.

Comment: @matt Thanks. I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var name: String { get }` is only a definition in the protocol. A conforming class, such as `MyModel` needs to implement the definition, like so:

```
class MyModel: NSObject, NSCoding, NSSecureCoding {

    var name: String { return "String Value here" }
}
```